# How to make managed preferences permanent on a client Mac without Lion Server?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, incognito-mode

I want the put the following plist in my Managed Preferences folder:
/Library/Managed Preferences/accountname/com.google.Chrome.plist

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>IncognitoModeAvailability</key>
   <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have sudo rights to do this.

But when I log out, the folder in Managed Preferences is deleted.

Does anyone how to make this permanent?

I want to do this to disable incognito mode in Chrome.

Has anyone tried this before on a Mac?

Comment: Never mind, I just found the answer myself.
Don't put it in Managed Preferences, but in /Library/Preferences/

That's it. Case closed.

Comment: How do I close this question without deleting it?

Comment: Take your comment and make it an answer to your own question, then mark it best answer.

Comment: Slim's solution is a workaround and does not answer the question as he posted it. I'm very much interested in the actual answer, as _some_ of the Chrome policy settings are NOT recognized when you place the `*.plist` file in `/Library/Preferences`; specifically, I want to set the `UserDataDir` setting, which is a per-user setting.